# How to check if a directory exists I don't know the exact name of it with a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, rhel

I need to check if a directory already exists, in this case the one with a number suffix, and I won't know the exact number. Example directories to search:

/usr/
names
names.backup
names.20160316

[[ -d /usr/names ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"

Comment: To get a proper answer, you'll have to explain what type of number you're looking form.

Comment: Similar to the above example, it will be the date of the file's backup, e.g. 20160203232229. The number itself is irrelevant to me, I just need a way to use regex or the equivalent to search for names.^(\d*)$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it all in bash and the file's backup date is always the same number of digits (i.e., yyyymmddhhmmssxx), then a bash file expansion expression like:

```
names.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

(one `[0-9]` for each digit) would match, but if the number sequence were a different number of digits, you would need an expression for each length.

A good description of file expansion options can be found in the [GNU Bash Manual Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) section.